# Can't connect to the Internet in NoxPlayer Android emulator for Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, android, emulator

I installed NoxPlayer 6.0.5 Android emulator in my Windows 7 and trying to register Viber account by phone number, but I receive error ***"Could not connect. An internet connection is required to set up Viber. Check your conenction and try again"***.

When I go to Wi-Fi settings of the emulator's Android I see only connection WiredSSID with status *"Saved"* and my Wi-Fi working connection, but with status *"Not in range"*. While I'm successfully connected to it in the same laptop where I'm trying NoxPlayer. When I click my working Wi-Fi there, I see only two buttons "Cancel" and "Forget"

How to make NoxPlayer to be connected to the Internet?